How to remove a Welcome view from General folder of Show View section in Eclipse?
I have a requirement to remove Welcome view from General folder under Show View.
Screenshot:https://i.sstatic.net/oGDzMpA4.png
I tried making xslt configuration to remove a view from General folder.But that doesn't work. This Welcome view option is configured under "org.eclipse.ui" jar under org.eclipse.ui.views plugin
Any idea to how to remove a view configured under org.eclipse.ui as per custom requirement ?
